# Botão de copiar conteúdo, e exibir uma mensagem logo depois que clicar nele pra copiar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Meu caso, eu quero fazer um botão para copiar o link curto de um site, ou seja não precisa exibir o texto, basta ter o ícone do fontawesome `<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>` ou seja, um botão com o ícone, sem mostrar o texto com o conteúdo igual o exemplo abaixo. ou seja, quando clicar no botão ele copiava a url curta do site.

**EXEMPLO DE OUTRO SITE**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [*ClipboardJS*](https://clipboardjs.com/) para realizar a cópia ou recorte de algum texto.

**Exemplo #1:**

```js
const clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    alert("Texto copiado")
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    alert("Falha ao copiar texto")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="Valdeir Psr">Copiar</button>
```

**Exemplo #2:**

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    
    /* Captura o nome original do botão */
    let textOriginal = e.trigger.textContent;
    
    /* Adiciona tooltip */
    e.trigger.classList.add("copied")
    
    /* Remove tooltip após 2 segundos */
    setTimeout( _ => {
      e.trigger.classList.remove("copied")
    }, 2000)

    e.clearSelection();
});
```

```css
/**
 * Tooltip Styles
 * Author Tooltip Styles: https://chrisbracco.com/a-simple-css-tooltip/
 */

/* Add this attribute to the element that needs a tooltip */
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the tooltip content by default */
[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Position tooltip above the element */
[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -129%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Triangle hack to make tooltip look like a speech bubble */
[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Show tooltip content on hover */
[data-tooltip].copied:before,
[data-tooltip].copied:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://clipboardjs.com/bower_components/primer-css/css/primer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<!-- Target -->
<textarea id="bar" rows="10" cols="50"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bz5yLUhvCbk" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></textarea>

<!-- Trigger -->
<button data-tooltip="Copiado" class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
    Copiar para área de transferência
</button>
```

Caso você esteja utilizando o *Boostrap*, basta utilizar `$("#element").tooltip("show")` para exibir a mensagem.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso: http://prntscr.com/jbtnza ??

Comment: @MatheusVitor Atualizei o exemplo

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito!